# dynamically changing value of nested object when using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a piece of state which looks as so:

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        dateOfBirth: {
            month: '',
            day: '',
            year: ''
        },
        phoneNumber: '',
        gender: '',
        interests: [],
        language: '',
        medicareNumber: ''
    })
```

I try to reassign the values of month day and year in the dateOfBirth object onChange, what is the syntax to do this and not overwrite any of the other keys in the object?

```
                        <input
                            value={values.dateOfBirth.month}
                            onChange={(e) => setValues({
                                ...values,
                                dateOfBirth: { month: e.target.value }
                            })}
                            type='number'
                            placeholder='MM'
                        />

                        <input
                            value={values.dateOfBirth.day}
                            onChange={(e) => setValues({
                                ...values,
                                dateOfBirth: { day: e.target.value }
                            })}
                            type='number'
                            placeholder='DD'
                        />
```

the code above is setting the value of dateOfBirth to only month or only day. But I need all the keys and values to remain the same and only change the value inside the respected key.

Comment: You can spread `dateOfBirth` inside itself before overwriting the key value pair you want

Comment: @Reyno  I figured it is possible. I just can't dial in the correct syntax. may you provide a code example?

Comment: For complex state it's recommended to use `useReducer`. You have more control over the state. `useState` is generally used for simple state variable like primitive values. https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<input
    value={values.dateOfBirth.month}
    onChange={(e) => setValues({
        ...values,
        dateOfBirth: {
            ...values.dateOfBirth,
            month: e.target.value
        }
    })}
    type='number'
    placeholder='MM'
/>
```

Or better, try not to have nested state properties.

Comment: I have 3 separate inputs for day month and year. It was the only way I could figure to do it? Any better solutions?

Comment: 1. use `<input type="date">`; 2. create a `<DatePicker>` component that returns a `Date` object, and store that inside your main form state.